# I need to know more about Invasion frequency

Tags: world-of-warcraft

How often do invasions like the one that just concluded in WOW happen and how do we know in advance?

Answer (score 6):

If you mean the pre-Legion invasion event, those types of events occur pretty much before an expansion. They're generally announced a month or two in advance on official Blizzard sites like their [news blog](https://worldofwarcraft.com/en-us/news/20175682/legion-demon-invasions-preview), the forums, the game launcher, the [pre-patch notes](https://worldofwarcraft.com/en-us/news/20166141/legion-pre-expansion-patch-now-live), and media sites that cover Blizzard games.

Some of the past expansions have also had an invasion:

- Before the Burning Crusade, the [dark portal opened and spewed forth
  demons plus a world boss](https://www.engadget.com/2012/08/03/wow-archivist-patch-2-0-3-the-first-pre-expansion-event/).
- Wrath of the Lich King had the [Lich King attack Stormwind and
  Orgrimmar and turned players into zombies with a plague](http://www.wowhead.com/forums&topic=48283/pre-wotlk-scourge-invasion-updated-11-10).
- Cataclysm had an [elemental invasion](http://www.wowhead.com/guide=cataclysm&prelaunch).
- Warlords of Draenor had the [Iron Horde invade the Blasted Lands](http://www.gameskinny.com/q8i5t/defend-against-iron-horde-invasion-in-limited-time-world-of-warcraft-patch-602-event).

Not all expansions have a world event: Mists of Panderia just had a scenario.

Occasionally, there also major events not tied to an expansion, but to the release of a new raid tier.  For example, the opening of the [Gates of Ahn'Qiraj in 1.9](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Gates_of_Ahn'Qiraj), and the [first scourge invasion](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Scourge_Invasion) heralding the coming of Naxxramas in 1.11.  You could also consider our taking of the [Isle of Quel'Danas in 2.4](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Isle_of_Quel%27Danas) and [the Isle of Thunder in 5.2](https://worldofwarcraft.com/en-us/news/8896363/5-2-the-thunder-king-patch-notes) as "world events" (less so the latter since much of it was linked to personal scenario progression) as these zones were gated pending server participation milestones in patch-related activities.

But generally, the big stuff tends to happen before an expansion.